# Database vs JavaScript string concatenation

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, json, oracle

I'm still relatively new to Angular UI framework, and I need to get user data including `user_id`, `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` from the database via API call and JSON payload.

This JSON payload has maybe 20 columns on it already and maybe about a 1k rows. Adding these 3 (id, firstname, lastname) wouldn't probably make a difference in a term of performance. The requirement is to display list of data including users data, where user is presented with "firstname lastname" as a concatenated string, and there will be some filtering on the users on the UI side, so there is ID for that.

My question is, does this concatenation logic belongs on DB layer as in instead of 3 columns back I return 2 like :

```
USER.USER_ID, USER.FIRST_NAME||' '||USER.LAST_NAME AS USER_NAME
```

Or on the front-end where I parse out the model like :

```
myModel = {
....
user_id: data.user_id,
user_name: data.user_firstname + ' ' + data.user_lastname,
}
```

Which approach would make more sense? I'm thinking the database should not have this business logic in there, so I'm fan of doing it on the front-end but I'm not sure.

Comment: I try to put as much load on the server as possible so the client can just output the data without much thought.  Then just use user_name_string as a variable from your server for your app to consume.

Answer (score 2):

Server layer has the 'horsepower' to handle the load better than the client.
Put your logic on the server layer whenever possible if performance is your main concern.

Answer (score 1):

At DB level, performance is always better than front-end because at front end side, differ configuration (RAM,Processor speed)differs performance. But Server side has configuration for performance improvement. 
   Also For data optimization of api, `gzip` compression at server side should be enabled.